# I can't unlock bootloader on fly fron linux

Tags: fastboot, bootloader

My OS is **majaro linux**.
My phone is **fly nimbus 8**.

I tried to unlock bootloader on it.
I followed the instruction.
First I go to the **Dev mod** then enable **OEM unlock** and **USB debugging**.
Second I typed:

> adb devices

output:

```
List of devices attached
56090913288827  device
```

Then I typed:

> adb reboot-bootloader

It became like this:
[image]

Then I checked again:

> fastboot devices

output:

```
56090913288827  fastboot
```

It seems all works out good!
But then I entered:

> sudo fastboot oem unlock

And then nothing. I mean absolutely nothing: it does not throw an error, not answers, not completes.
By the way, the phone does the same - absolutely nothing!
if I plug off the device it writes:

```
FAILED (Status read failed (No such device))
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

I tried it already ten more times but it doesn't want to work!

Does anyone know what the problem?
Did somebody have the experience in flash the **fly**(in particular **nimbus 8**)?
I'll de be waiting for an answer!
Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why but Mediatek devices (which your device is) do not have bootloader support via fastboot. If you are looking to install a custom recovery or a ROM, you need to use SP Flash Tool. Visit its site to know about is usage.

Comment: @Firelord This is the case! If I wanna install custom recovery I need to unlock bootloader! I already tried SP flash tool, but again, when I click download it do nothing. However, when I start it from the terminal it sees when i plug in or plug out the device. PS. Sorry for my grammar!

Comment: try `fastboot flashing unlock` from windows with latest platform tools, linux platform tools have issues sometimes. SP Flash Tool can flash boot/recovery with locked bootloader. Do a readback first! Then try to flash stock boot/stock recovery first. if you can flash boot only, you can root with Magisk and write recovery with dd. if your device have MTK secure boot you need to find Secure Boot Download Agent

Comment: btw you have not installed Mediatek preloader VCOM drivers, you really need Windows for it. device must switched off for readback/flashing (flash with removed battery if possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the matter!
**Fly nimbus 8**  delivers in two kinds: with **MTK** and with **spreadtrum**!
In my case it was with **spreadtrum**.